# How to deal with customer projects needing customized components

Tags: angular

## The requirement

I want to develop an application which has a standard implementation but also leaves the possibility to do some customization (for customers). This customization can be on the behavior, style or templates of any component or functionalities. I would like a solution where I am not forced to add something to the customer project in case it is not directly impacted (on what it is customized).

## The current approach

I have my standard project alongside the customer projects. Every customer project is overriding the module/components/services... where it needs customization.

- projects

  - standard
  - customer1
  - customer2
  - customerN

## The current problem with this solution

When overriding a component, I have to override the whole template. So If I would like to just add a

inside my customized component, I have to copy paste the whole original template and add the

where I need it.
The problem with this is that if I want now to add something to the standard template, the customized one won't be affected unless I also add the new thing to its template making the maintenance of customer projects harder.

(Already tried to find a solution in [Make changes in template when overriding a component in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660235/make-changes-in-template-when-overriding-a-component-in-angular))
I could have a JIT working solution with the use of ngTemplateOutlet and template composition (template: require('part1.html') + require('part2.html')) but this does not work with AOT (Angular 8)

## Question

Is the overall approach (overriding) for this requirement a valid approach ?
I would like to avoid using lot of ngIf in only one project to deal with customer implementation.

If not, what would be your suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your requirements might be a valid match for a dynamic component loader. The Angular documentation has a good example regarding this:
[Angular Dynamic Component Loader example](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

By using this you won't need to have a lot of ngIf's in your project for each customer. You could just have a single base and for some customers load a specific component

Comment: I felt that it would not fit the case where I want to add something like <h1>additional title><p>additional paragraph</p><img src="additional image/> so several dom elements which are not part of a component (to not add another dom layer). Or if I just want to add a mot form field for example.